# How to understand principles of bulk insert statement in mssql?

Tags: sql-server

description:

> step 1. I use bulk insert statement import some data

e.g.

```
 1,a,b

 2,a,b

 10,a,b
```

> step 2. I read this data using with(nolock) and append where field > minRange, yep , I want got a range data.
>
> step 3. I could got data, but the result like this:

```
 1,a,b
 10,a,b
```

> 

my problem?

why, 2 could be ignore?
 i found 10 will be inserted into table before then 2,  when i use wit(nolock).

Comment: Can you show the command from step 2 to read and append?

Comment: Because you're using `WITH(NOLOCK)` when reading the data. That specifically tells the database to not block any other process, or wait for any other process to finish. This means that you could read the table after the INSERT had started but before it has finished...

Comment: @mcalex,  very simple sql statement ,  select top 10 * from table with(nolock) where id>1

Comment: What is your statement for (where field > minRange as you mentioned) ?

Comment: Suggestion after your edit : don't use `WITH(NOLOCK)` then?

Comment: @MatBailie,  yes,  i  could understand the keyword with(nolock), but, i puzzle, why 10 will be written to the table than 2.  i think ,it should be written by order(1,2,10), through, i use a read uncommited.

Comment: @HardikShah, sorry, puzzle u, i want to say where condition: like where id>1

Comment: NO, there are no guarantees about data being written to the table. A bulk insert is atomic, there is a guarantee that all of it is written, or none of it. But you have chosen to use 'dirty reads'.  There are complexities such as Pages on the disc, binary tree indexes, other concurrent activity, etc, etc. ZERO GUARANTEES are made for how an atomic action is completed. You should read the help on NOLOCK before using it.  The ONLY thing you know is that you're reading data in the middle of an action that's not complete, you can not predict what parts have or have not completed.

Comment: @MatBailie has got it.  But how does 1,a,b make it into results when query is `where id>1`

Comment: @MatBailie very good!! thks,  bulk insert is atomic, if i want to improve read performance and get a order data,  what's u suggestions?

Comment: @mcalex, it‘s my mistake , where id>=1

Comment: if you want the data ordered, you need a field (eg 'sortorder') to implement that.